# Go Daddy Economy Windows Hosting Issue with ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, web-config, windows-hosting

Go Daddy has told me the reason my website is not working is due to the web.config file but haven't, can't, or won't tell me why exactly. I think it would be the same with any host using plesk. I haven't added to or altered the web.config file that vs generated at all. Anyone know what needs to be changed for the site to be hosted with plesk?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please 
visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework"
      type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, 
EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      requirePermission="false"/>
 </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial 
 Catalog=aspnet-WebSite3-dc1d217f-11d8-4c59-a3eb- 
 70b83e3aa30f;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebSite3-dc1d217f- 
11d8- 
4c59-a3eb-70b83e3aa30f.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
   <pages>
      <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity"/>
  </namespaces>
  <controls>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" 
namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <!--
      ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
    -->
    <clear/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<profile>
  <providers>
    <!--
      ASP.NET Membership Profile is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
    -->
    <clear/>
  </providers>
</profile>
<roleManager>
  <!--
        ASP.NET Membership Role is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
    -->
  <providers>
    <clear/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<!--
        If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
        you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
        change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
        of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
  -->
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider"
      type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
      connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
  </providers>
</sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
</modules>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, 
EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
</providers>
</entityFramework>
<system.codedom>
<compilers>
  <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"

type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
    type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
</compilers>
</system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

I having had to deploy a site to Go Daddy before so I am hoping that someone can shed some light on the subject.

I don't get an error message attempting to browse the site, just the generic message that happens when an exception is thrown and the error can't be shown:

Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What kind of error message did you get? Could you show the exception message?

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Trust level of your web application.

[Click here to know more.](https://in.godaddy.com/help/what-trust-level-can-i-use-when-running-aspnet-2531)

Comment: That didn't seem to make any difference. It was already set to medium though.

Comment: Trust level should be full. Also can you share the URL of your website or give some more details of the current error.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be more painful than it is worth, threw a temporary html website up and am working on moving the hosting to AWS.